# How to know the number of controls(they can be added at compile-time or run-time) of a dialog in MFC

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc

Is there anyway to find out number of controls at run-time for a dialog in VC++.

Comment: Look into [EnumChildWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494(v=vs.85).aspx) with the containing frame/dialog specified as the parent.

Comment: @LPs: Presumably because the Windows API exposes a C interface.

Answer (score 0):

No, not in general way. The suggested `EnumChildWindows()` or `GetWindow()` with `GW_CHILD` plus `GetNextWindow()` can be instructed to enumerate nested windows or not. But the problem is - how do you know if you should? A composite control may have multiple child windows that are NOT dialog controls, while there might be a window that groups multiple controls as their parent...

You need to specify - what exactly do you want to count. And, possibly - why? As this information may not mean much to you after all.